# New nav filters fail to work on HTTPS

Tags: bug, status-completed, new-nav, ssl

On HTTPS, the JavaScript used to update the URL when changing the filter is hardcoded to use plaintext HTTP; it should be protocol-relative.:

[image: nav filters image]

> Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/need-answers?show=7&sort=newest' cannot be created in a document with origin 'https://stackoverflow.com'.

This is in Chrome 44, on all of the tabs.

Comment: currently fixinating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (build rev `2015.7.24.3606` on MSE/MSO, `2015.7.24.2748` on sites).